# php - return two times everytime a function is called

Tags: php

I'm trying to make it so everytime I call the function, it should returns one in two times the number like this:

```
calls(); // NULL
calls(); // 2
calls(); // NULL
calls(); // 4
```

Here is my code:

```
function calls() {
    if (NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        $calls++;
        return $calls;
    }
}


calls(); // NULL
calls(); // 2
calls(); // NULL
calls(); // 4
```

Comment: Something with a `variable` and `% modulo`. `% $var/2 == 0`.

Comment: Make use of a static variable and return the value when it's even.

Comment: Functions normally don't have any persistent state. You need a class or closure to hold state between function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a global variable, use a `static` variable in the function in question:

```
function count_calls() {
     static $count = 0;
     ++$count;
     return ($count % 2 === 0) ? $count : NULL ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do as example:

```
$current = 0;
$current = calls($current); // NULL
echo display($current);
$current = calls($current); // 2
echo display($current);
$current = calls($current); // NULL
echo display($current);
$current = calls($current); // 4
echo display($current);

/**
* Do stuff for your call with in param your last call pointer and returns new pointer
**/
function calls($last) {
     return $last++;
}

/**
* Returns null if not even, else the pointer value
**/
function display($value){

    if ($value % 2 = 0)
         return $value;
    return null;
}
```

Of course it would be easier in object if you store your current pointer inside a $this->current, but I don't think with the code you show it is appropriated to your understanding at moment! Have fun with it already

```
$class = new Call();
$class->calls();
echo $class->display();
$class->calls();
echo $class->display();
$class->calls();
echo $class->display();
$class->calls();
echo $class->display();
    class Call {

        private $current = 0;

        /**
        * Do stuff for your call with in param your last call pointer and returns new pointer
        **/
        function calls() {
             $this->current++:
             return $this->current;
        }

        /**
        * Returns null if not even, else the pointer value
        **/
        function display(){

            if ($this->current % 2 = 0)
                 return $this->current;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I have to do it without using any parameters

Comment: updated in object, please note that you can merge my 2 functions if you want, I just made it separated because it is easier to understand

Comment: I just updated also the echo to return the value, please note that the fact that I return the current in calls function is now obsolete in my example, but might be useful to you based on what you do outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code :

```
$calls = 0;

function calls() {
    $GLOBALS['calls']++;
    if ($GLOBALS['calls'] % 2 != 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        //$GLOBALS['calls']++;
        return $GLOBALS['calls'];
    }
}


var_dump(calls()); // NULL
var_dump(calls()); // 2
var_dump(calls()); // NULL
var_dump(calls()); // 4
```